# What is the equivalent to eb setenv in aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the equivalent command of eb setenv in AWS cli?

I tried option_settings but seems like it only holds the namespaces not the random variables.

Note: I do not want to set them on aws web interface or .ebextensions config files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment` command.

From [the examples on this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html#examples) from the AWS CLI docs:

> **To set an environment variable**
>
> The following command sets the value of the "PARAM1" variable in the
>   "my-env" environment to "ParamValue":
>
> ```
> aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env
> --option-settings Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment,OptionName=PARAM1,Value=ParamValue
> ```